El Gamal decryption without knowing private key
I stumbled upon a problem while studying el gamal. p,q,g,h and r,t are known and r,t is acquired by flawed implementation of the algorithm
    # Encryption
def Enc(message, h, q, p, g): # m is the message
    m = int.from_bytes(message, byteorder='big')
    k = random.randint(1, 2**16-1)
    r = pow(g, k, p)
    t = (pow(h, k, p)*m)%p
    return r, t



# Decryption
def Dec(r, t, s, q, p, g):
    m = (pow(r, q-s, p)*t)%p 
    
    return m.to_bytes((m.bit_length()+7)//8, byteorder='big')

I see that k should be in range 1,n-1  and decryption should be done t* r^-s modp. Other than that I don't see a flaw and don't see any way to exploit it to get the s or the message. r^q modp returns 1 so it should work as it should be t* r^-s modp. Any help is appreciated. I know h= g^s modp, so it is not possible to find s. We know g^q modp =1 since q is the order and r^qmodp = 1 what does it say?

Since this is an exercise, I won't give you the answer.  But:

I see that k should be in range 1,n-1 ... Other than that I don't see a flaw and don't see any way to exploit it to get the s or the message.

Why don't you consider that?  If you have $r= g^k$ for $k \in [1, 65535]$, can you recover $k$?  How would you use the value of $k$ to recover $m$?

for some reason 2^16 seemed a lot bigger than it is
